# получение значений из массива и вставка нового элемента

Tags: javascript

Есть:

- массив следующего вида:

  ```
  mass = [tr.link_group_header, tr.link_group_header, tr.link_group_header]
  ```

  На разных страницах содержание массива разное, верней оно одинаковое, но повторяется разное количество раз. на одной странице оно может быть таким:

  ```
  [tr.link_group_header, tr.link_group_header, tr.link_group_header]
  ```

  а на другой таким:

  ```
  [tr.link_group_header, tr.link_group_header, tr.link_group_header, 
    tr.link_group_header, tr.link_group_header]
  ```
- переменная `x`. Она равняется длине массива `mass`. В зависимости от того, сколько элементов в массиве, меняется ее значение в числовом эквиваленте. Т.е., `x` может равняться и "3", и "5", и т.п.
- также имеется `id="name_"`

Как сделать так, чтоб при загрузке страницы в массив `mass` вставлялся тег `<b id="name_1">` перед каждым `tr`? При этом в `id` подставлялся порядковый номер?

Т.е., если на странице в массиве три таких элемента `tr.link_group_header`, то для трех `tr` последовательно задаётся три `id` (`id="name_1"`, `id="name_2"`, `id="name_3"`).

Я пока додумался только до следующего:

```
var mass = document.getElementsByClassName("link_group_header"); //получаем вот такой массив: 
// HTMLCollection
// [tr.link_group_header, tr.link_group_header, tr.link_group_header, tr.link_group_header, tr.link_group_header, tr.link_group_header]

var kol = mass.length; // получаем кол-во элементов в полученном массиве. Эта цифра будет определять кол-во порядковых номеров в id'шниках
var link_pref = "link_"; // создаем переменную с основой класса
var link_nomber = тут какая-то магия, теоритически, тут может использоваться переменная "kol"; // создаем переменную с генерирующимся порядковым номером для класса
var link_full = link_pref + link_nomber; // создаем переменную с полным классом, склеив основу и порядковый номер

и вот тут должна произойти основная магия по вставлению тега с айдишником.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть отличный метод для работы с массивами: *map*, возвращает вновь сгенерированный массив с помощью ф-ции-параметра.
На деле

```
var mass = [/*ваш массив*/];
var ids = mass.map(function (el, i) { 
   /*
       el - текущий элемент итерации
       i - его индекс,
       в новый массив будут заноситься значения, которые возвращает ф-ция
   */
   return "name_" + i;
});

ids; // [массив типа "name_{index}"];
```

Comment: о, спасибо большое. сейчас буду вникать. заодно подробнее почитаю об этом методе.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=mass.length-1; i>=0; --i)
  mass.splice(i, 0, '<b id="' + id+ (i+1) + '">' );
```

Comment: благодарю. тоже опробую сейчас. о результате отпишусь чуть позже.